# Use of 'какой' in a sentence

Tags: грамматика, падежи

In the sentence 'в *какой* стране ты живёшь', I don't understand why 'какой' is in the nominative rather than the prepositional case (like стране).

Is this a special use of the interrogative pronouns here?

Comment: страна is feminine, so какой is not in the nominative here.

Comment: ThankS very much for explanation Richard

Answer (score 4):

If you look at this [declension table](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9) for the pronominal adjective *какой*, you will see that this particular form is used in six different gender/case/number combinations.

One of them is the feminine prepositional, which, as you correctly mentioned, is what the (feminine) noun *стране* is in.